# Django Heroku, This site can’t be reached, Took too long to respond

Tags: python, django, heroku

I created a Django website around 1 month ago, it was working perfectly fine, but on 8-11-2020 it stopped working (It won't load). I tried things that I could find on the internet but nothing worked as there isn't much about my problem. I tried restarting all dynos and redeploying my website but it didn't work.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Yup, same here. None of my sites are working. Hosted on US servers. Haven't been working since at least yesterday; that was when I checked last. Heroku status seems fine, and there is a maintenance scheduled for today, but it should be working now. Pretty shambolic tbh. No idea what's going on.

Comment: You probably won't get any helpful responses. This isn't really the sort of question suited for stack overflow. At best, if you should post error messages, you might get some help. Otherwise, you should contact heroku

Answer (score 0):

This can be an issue in your internet connection

For more info: https://kinsta.com/blog/err_connection_timed_out/

Answer (score 0):

This is a network problem from your end. My projects aren't opening from my home wifi, but they are on mobile data. Check your firewall and with your ISP.

Comment: Now the problem is solved automatically although it took around 1 day. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem since today morning. I have a rails app that was working flawlessly for close to 1 year on hobby dyno. But at least since today morning, I am getting timed out. I haven't changed anything in the app. I tried scaling up dynos as well. I have now submitted a ticket to heroku, waiting for their response.